# Magic box problem

Tags: code-golf

You have an input array of size m*n. Each cell in the array is populated with either P or T. The only operation you can do on the array is flip columns. When you flip a column, the letters in all the cells of that column switch (P becomes T and viceversa). If you have 'x' number of rows with same letter (e.g. PPPP) then you get a point. Design an algorithm that takes in the array and returns a solution (which columns to flip)  such that the resulting array has maximum number of points possible.

Note: In case there are multiple solutions that yield the highest score, choose the one with lowest number of flips. Example:

Input Array:

```
PPTPP
PPTPP
PPTTP
PPPTT
PPPTT
```

Output:

```
3
```

Explanation: 
A solution that yields the highest points: Flip column no. 3
Then the original array would be:

```
PPPPP // 1 point
PPPPP // 1 point
PPPTP
PPTTT
PPTTT

//Total: 2 points
```

Note that one could also flip columns 4 and 5 to get a score of two, but that needs an additional flip.

You may use any convenient input format to represent the two dimensional array, and you may also any two distinct, but fixed, values to represent `P` and `T`.

This is code golf, so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. This is a great challenge, but it needs a winning criterion to be on topic.

Comment: Can I control the input format? Can I say P is False and T is True? If not, what is the input format?

Comment: Sure, the input format does not matter. Say you have a two directional array of chars or ints or booleans or whatever type you choose.

Comment: You need a winning criterion to decide which of the valid answers is the best. Assuming a valid answer has to give the maximum points for the input grid (BTW you should state this), it should be possible to bruteforce a 32 column grid in reasonable time. Therefore I suggest you make i a codegolf (shortest code wins)

Comment: Added the criterion. How is it now?

Comment: I don't have time to do an edit myself, but some suggestions for improvement: 1. Edit the question to say that input can use any two distinct values, don't leave it in the comments. 2. This isn't a [tag:programming-puzzle]. It *may* be a [tag:puzzle-solver]. Read the tag description before adding that tag. 3. It would be a better test case if it didn't have the same value as both the number of the column to flip and the number of rows achieved.

Comment: I've worked in Peter's first suggestion. Feel free to change the wording if you don't like it.

Comment: Do I get 2 points if one row all `T`s and one row is all `P`s?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, yes you get two points in that case.

Comment: "Any convenient input format," you say. Can I ask for each row as an integer, where the binary representation of that integer has a 0 for P and a 1 for T? That would seem a very convenient format for this challenge. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 37

```
{x/1+⍳⍴x←y[↑⍋(+/∘.≠⍨2⊥⍉y),¨+/y←⍵⍪~⍵]}
```

Example:

```
{x/1+⍳⍴x←y[↑⍋(+/∘.≠⍨2⊥⍉y),¨+/y←⍵⍪~⍵]} 5 5⍴0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
```

[Tested here.](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%7Bx/1+%u2373%u2374x%u2190y%5B%u2191%u234B%28+/%u2218.%u2260%u23682%u22A5%u2349y%29%2C%A8+/y%u2190%u2375%u236A%7E%u2375%5D%7D%205%205%u23740%200%201%200%200%200%200%201%200%200%200%200%201%201%200%200%200%200%201%201%200%200%200%201%201)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 28

```
f@eo+/QN/Qm!dN_osZ^U2lhQTUhQ
```

Takes input in the form of a nested list, e.g.

```
[[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1]]
```

Gives output 0-indexed, e.g.

```
[2]
```

`^U2lhQ`: Generates all possible lists of 0s and 1s of the right length.

`_osZ`: Orders these lists from most 1s to least.

`+/QN/Qm!dN`: Counts how many times each list (`N`) and its inverse, 0s and 1s swapped (`m!dN`) occur in the input. The former corresponds to a series of flips leaving all zeros, the latter to leaving all ones.

`eo`: Orders the list by the above key, and takes its last element, which will be the result with the most matching columns, and among them the one with the least ones.

`f@ ... TUhQ`: Converts this list of 1s and 0s to a list of indices to be flipped.

For 1-indexing, change the `d` to a `k`, then put `mhd` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 98

```
g s=snd$maximum[((sum[1|o<-s,o==r||o==map(1-)r],-sum r),[i|(i,1)<-zip[1..]r])|r<-s++map(map(1-))s]
```

input format is a list of list of ints. you can use a string version for testing:

```
gg = g . map (map (\c -> case c of 'T' -> 0 ; _ -> 1) ) . lines
```

<sub>oh no the spaces! it hurts!</sub>

this works by iterating over the rows and calculating the number of points we will get if we flipped the columns in a way that this row gains us a point.

first thing to notice is that flipping the row to either all `True` or all `False` doesn't matter, because the grids will be exactly the inverse of each other and thus will have the exact same score.

the way we calculate the count when a given row gains a point is so: we iterate over the rows again, and sum the points each row gives us, using the fact that they do exactly when the rows are either identical or the exact inverse.

for example, if the row we are flipping is `TPPTP` and the current row we are iterating over is `PTTPT` or `TPPTP` then the row gains us a point, but when it's any other row, it doesn't gain us any points.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, I will fix it shortly (hopefully)

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
l~z:X,,La\{1$f++}/{,}${X\{_X=:!t}/z{_&,(},,}$0=:)S*
```

This reads a two-dimensional array of 0s and 1s from STDIN. E.g. the example in the question would be

```
[[0 0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 1 0] [0 0 0 1 1] [0 0 0 1 1]]
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

This first gets all possible subsets of columns, in order of increasing length, then performs the flips for each subsets and sorts them by how many rows still have both 0s and 1s in them. Finally, we just return the first such subset. This relies on the sorting being stable, such that the initial order of increasing length takes care of the tie-breaker.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 37

```
q~_{:!}%+:T{T1$a-,\0-+}$0={U):U*}%0-`
```

Input format:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 1 0] [0 0 0 1 1] [0 0 0 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica - 76

```
{
{P, P, T, P, P},
{P, P, T, P, P},
{P, P, T, T, P},
{P, P, P, T, T},
{P, P, P, T, T}
}/.{P -> 1, T -> 0};
First@MaximalBy[
  Subsets@Range@Length[%],
  MapAt[1-#&,%,{All,#}]~Count~{1..}&
]
```

Comment: Unless specified otherwise snippets aren't valid submissions. [You'll need to write either a function or a full program taking input.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 234

```
from itertools import *
A=input()
n=len(A[0])
R=range(n)
S=(0,)
for p in[q for i in R[:-1] for q in combinations(R,i)]:
    s=[sum([(l[q]+(q in p))%2 for q in R])for l in A]
    m=s.count(n)+s.count(0)
    if m>S[0]:S=(m,p)
print S[1]
```

Input is a list of lists:

```
[[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1]]
```

Output is a tuple of flips using python indexing from 0:

```
(2,)
```

If the output must be indexed from 1, then the code is 272 characters with 0 denoting no flips:

```
print 0 if len(S[1])==0 else [p+1 for p in S[1]]
```